# FlatList `onEndReached` callback is not called when swipe to the end of the list

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

The [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html) component has a [onEndReached prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#onendreached). I am implementing a simple feature that when user swipe the screen to the end of the list, the app sends a new request to get more items to the list from backend. The following is what I tried:

I firstly created a custom component `MyCustomList` which is just a wrapper of `FlatList`. There are two props `items` and `getMore`.

```
const MyCustomList = ({items, getMore}) => {
      ...
      return (
          <FlatList
            keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
            data={items}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            onEndReached={getMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
            ListFooterComponent={myFooter}
    />
  );
  ...
  export default MyCustomList;
}
```

- `items` are the data to be shown on the `FlatList`,
- `getMore` is the function that send request to backend to get more items. It is supposed to be called when swiped to the end of the list.

In my screen component, I use above `MyCustomList` component as below:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import MyCustomList from '../components/MyCustomList';
import {useQuery} from 'react-query';

const MyScreen = ({navigation}) => {

       const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

       // when screen is rendered, get the data from backend
       const {data, status} = useQuery('my-items', httpClient.fetchItems);

       // this is the function passed to MyCustomList component
       const getMoreItems = () => {
         // I expected to see this log every time when user swiped to the end of the list
         console.log('get next 10 items');
         setPage(page + 1);
      };

       return (
         <View>
            ...
            <MyCustomList items={data} getMore={getMoreItems} />
         </View>);
  };
```

As you can see, in my screen component I pass the `getMoreItems` function to `MyCustomList`.

When I run my app, I only see that log message I put inside `getMoreItems` function once when the screen is first time shown. It's weird to me that I haven't swiped to the end of the list at that point.  After that, every time when I swipe to the end of the list, the `getMoreItems` is not triggered (I don't see that log message). Why is that?

P.S. when swiping to the bottom of the list, my screen is not re-rendered now because the `getMoreItems` is not triggered the `setPage(page+1)` is not called.

Comment: Dear @Leem.fin, have you ever tried to increase onEndReachedThreshold value bigger than 0, like 0.1?

Comment: yes, I have tried that.